# MYSQL inserting multiple rows from table from one user to other users in a multiple loops is inserting only last result

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to copy all results from **client_id 67 in relations table**, to all other users from users_groups table, so id's 99, 111, 130 **must have same results in relations table like id 67**.

So all query's works fine, update works fine, deleting too, but Insert won't insert any data to relations table for that other id's i need.

I searched stackoverflow but didn't find any solution that might work in my example.

Relations table and results for user id 67 that i need to copy data from

```
signal_providers_relations TABLE

| id | client_id | provider_id | active_sp | subscription_sp | created_by | cr_datetime | ea_settings_active_sp | ea_settings_sp          | up_datetime | sp_risk_allocation | sp_max_trades |
|----|-----------|-------------|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------------------|-------------|--------------------|---------------|
| 1  |  67       |  12         | Y         | 0000-00-00      | user123    | 2018-04-09  | Y                     | 0|1|0|1|1|2||1.0|0|0|1  | 2018-04-09  | 100                | 0             |
| 2  |  67       |  4          | N         | 0000-00-00      | user1      | 2018-04-10  | Y                     | 1|1|1|1|0|0|1|00|0|0|2  | 2018-04-10  | 120                | 1             | 
| 3  |  67       |  5          | Y         | 0000-00-00      | test23     | 2018-04-11  | N                     | 2|1|0|2|1|5|1|11|1|2|1  | 2018-04-11  | 95                 | 1             |
```

Users groups table

```
users_groups TABLE

| id | user_id | group_id | user_role |
|----|---------|----------|-----------|
| 1  | 130     | 94       | 0         |
| 2  | 111     | 94       | 0         |
| 3  | 99      | 94       | 0         |
| 4  | 67      | 94       | 1         |
```

Here is code:

```
    $user_role = intval($_POST['user_role']);
    $userID = intval($_POST['user_id']);
    $groupID = intval($_POST['group_id']);
    $ea_settings = $_POST['ea_settings'];

    // get users from group to apply ea_settings
    $get_users = "SELECT a.group_name, b.user_id, b.user_role, b.group_id, c.email, c.ea_settings
            FROM user_groups a
            INNER JOIN users_groups b ON b.group_id = a.id
            INNER JOIN www_users c ON c.id = b.user_id
            WHERE a.id = '".$groupID."'";
    $pr = fetch_array($get_users);

    // get special user relations
    $query2 = "SELECT a.*, b.user_role
               FROM signal_providers_relations a
               INNER JOIN users_groups b ON a.client_id = b.user_id
               WHERE a.client_id = '".$userID."' AND b.user_role = '1'";
    $pr2 = fetch_array($query2);

    // get number of items from special user
    $query3 = "SELECT count(a.id) as cnt
                FROM signal_providers_relations a
                INNER JOIN users_groups b ON a.client_id = b.user_id
                WHERE a.client_id = '".$userID."' AND b.user_role = '1'";
    $pr3 = fetch_array($query3);

    // update all users where id = all id's from group, apply ea_settings to all id's from Special user 
    foreach ($pr as $key) {
        foreach ($pr2 as $r) {
            foreach ($pr3 as $s) {

                $user_id = intval($key['user_id']); // id of all users

                // update users
                $update_users = "UPDATE www_users SET ea_settings = '".$ea_settings."' WHERE id = '".$user_id."'";

                if (exec_query_confirm($update_users)) {

                    // first delete all user record in relations that are not special users, delete all record if user is have role = 0, and insert new data
                    if ($key['user_role'] == '0') {
                        $delete_relations = "DELETE FROM signal_providers_relations WHERE client_id = '".$user_id."'";
                        exec_query($delete_relations);

                        // loop through special user records and add to other users
                        for ($i=0; $i < $s['cnt']; $i++) { 

                            // $s['cnt'] = 10 = number of records in relations table from id 67

                            $insert_new_values = "INSERT INTO signal_providers_relations (client_id, provider_id, active_sp, subscription_sp, created_by, cr_datetime, ea_settings_active_sp, ea_settings_sp, up_datetime, sp_risk_allocation, sp_max_trades) 
                                       VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$r['provider_id']."', '".$r['active_sp']."', '".$r['subscription_sp']."', '".$r['created_by']."', '".$r['cr_datetime']."', '".$r['ea_settings_active_sp']."', '".$r['ea_settings_sp']."', '".$r['up_datetime']."', '".$r['sp_risk_allocation']."', '".$r['sp_max_trades']."')";
                          exec_query($insert_new_values);

                        } 
                    }
                } else {
                    $err = 61;
                }
            } // foreach
        } // foreach
    } // foreach

}
```

So basically i need this

```
| id | client_id | provider_id | active_sp | subscription_sp | created_by | cr_datetime | ea_settings_active_sp | ea_settings_sp          | up_datetime | sp_risk_allocation | sp_max_trades |
|----|-----------|-------------|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------------------|-------------|--------------------|---------------|
| 1  |  99       |  12         | Y         | 0000-00-00      | user123    | 2018-04-09  | Y                     | 0|1|0|1|1|2||1.0|0|0|1  | 2018-04-09  | 100                | 0             |
| 2  |  99       |  4          | N         | 0000-00-00      | user1      | 2018-04-10  | Y                     | 1|1|1|1|0|0|1|00|0|0|2  | 2018-04-10  | 120                | 1             | 
| 3  |  99       |  5          | Y         | 0000-00-00      | test23     | 2018-04-11  | N                     | 2|1|0|2|1|5|1|11|1|2|1  | 2018-04-11  | 95                 | 1             |

| id | client_id | provider_id | active_sp | subscription_sp | created_by | cr_datetime | ea_settings_active_sp | ea_settings_sp          | up_datetime | sp_risk_allocation | sp_max_trades |
|----|-----------|-------------|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------------------|-------------|--------------------|---------------|
| 1  |  111      |  12         | Y         | 0000-00-00      | user123    | 2018-04-09  | Y                     | 0|1|0|1|1|2||1.0|0|0|1  | 2018-04-09  | 100                | 0             |
| 2  |  111      |  4          | N         | 0000-00-00      | user1      | 2018-04-10  | Y                     | 1|1|1|1|0|0|1|00|0|0|2  | 2018-04-10  | 120                | 1             | 
| 3  |  111      |  5          | Y         | 0000-00-00      | test23     | 2018-04-11  | N                     | 2|1|0|2|1|5|1|11|1|2|1  | 2018-04-11  | 95                 | 1             |

| id | client_id | provider_id | active_sp | subscription_sp | created_by | cr_datetime | ea_settings_active_sp | ea_settings_sp          | up_datetime | sp_risk_allocation | sp_max_trades |
|----|-----------|-------------|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------------------|-------------|--------------------|---------------|
| 1  |  130      |  12         | Y         | 0000-00-00      | user123    | 2018-04-09  | Y                     | 0|1|0|1|1|2||1.0|0|0|1  | 2018-04-09  | 100                | 0             |
| 2  |  130      |  4          | N         | 0000-00-00      | user1      | 2018-04-10  | Y                     | 1|1|1|1|0|0|1|00|0|0|2  | 2018-04-10  | 120                | 1             | 
| 3  |  130      |  5          | Y         | 0000-00-00      | test23     | 2018-04-11  | N                     | 2|1|0|2|1|5|1|11|1|2|1  | 2018-04-11  | 95                 | 1             |
```

Comment: Are you executing `$insert_new_values`?

Comment: Yes i forgot to add ```exec_query($insert_new_values);``` but with that i get inserted only last value 10 times for each id as you can see on image http://prntscr.com/jg35ib and it need to be like this for every other id except 67 https://prnt.sc/jg36mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you don't actually need the third query or loop (the `foreach` on `$pr2` achieves the same as the `for` on `$s['cnt']`). You should be doing this:

```
// update all users where id = all id's from group, apply ea_settings to all id's from Special user 
foreach ($pr as $key) {
    $user_id = intval($key['user_id']); // id of all users
    // update users
    $update_users = "UPDATE www_users SET ea_settings = '".$ea_settings."' WHERE id = '".$user_id."'";
    if (exec_query_confirm($update_users)) {
        // first delete all user record in relations that are not special users, delete all record if user is have role = 0, and insert new data
        if ($key['user_role'] == '0') {
            $delete_relations = "DELETE FROM signal_providers_relations WHERE client_id = '".$user_id."'";
            exec_query($delete_relations);
            // loop through special user records and add to other users
            foreach ($pr2 as $r) {
                $insert_new_values = "INSERT INTO signal_providers_relations (client_id, provider_id, active_sp, subscription_sp, created_by, cr_datetime, ea_settings_active_sp, ea_settings_sp, up_datetime, sp_risk_allocation, sp_max_trades) 
                                       VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$r['provider_id']."', '".$r['active_sp']."', '".$r['subscription_sp']."', '".$r['created_by']."', '".$r['cr_datetime']."', '".$r['ea_settings_active_sp']."', '".$r['ea_settings_sp']."', '".$r['up_datetime']."', '".$r['sp_risk_allocation']."', '".$r['sp_max_trades']."')";
                exec_query($insert_new_values);
            } // foreach
        } else {
            $err = 61;
        }
    } // if
} // foreach
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine, i forgot that i already have that in first query :/